# onClick at button in Fragment desn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

In my app I have tabbed activity with two fragments. At the fragment I want to use button to open dialog alert. But for five hours now I'm struggling with actual clicking on button. I tried ways with making onClick with xml, Implement `OnClickListener` But nothing worked. The button is just doing nothing. I tried to debug it and it seems that `onCreateView` method is not called at all. Any tips?

```
public class PlayersFragment extends Fragment {

public PlayersFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_players, container, false);
    Button addButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "YES is clicked!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: add code of tab activity

Comment: make sure that the xml view `R.layout.fragment_players` contains the `Button` widget with the view `id` of `R.id.add_button` and as stated use `onViewCreated` callback for widget view hierarchy initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onViewCreated` method in your fragment class. Then put the `onClickListener` on your Button with the method.